# Firebase emulator cloud functions only works with default us-central1 location in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

### Context

when trying to call a firebase cloud function in the emulator from Flutter (tried both on Web & IOS), I always get an internal error if the location is set to anything but the default us-central1.

```
Error: [firebase_functions/internal] internal
```

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that when I set up the Cloud Functions emulator, I have to specify the location too.

```
FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'europe-west2').useFunctionsEmulator('localhost', 5001);
```

### Note

That's is different from calling the function.

```
await FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'europe-west2').httpsCallable('testFun3').call();
```

Comment: is there no way doing this with environment variables or command line parameters when starting emulator?